# Should a default implementation of an interface with stub methods be abstract?

Tags: java, object

Suppose I have an interface

```java
interface MyInterface {
  void doSomething();
  void doSomethingElse();
  /* way more methods */
}
```

and maybe a default implementation like this:

```java
class StubbedMyInterface implements MyInterace {
  void doSomething() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
  }

  void doSomethingElse() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
  }
  /* all the other methods */
}
```

The stubbed class simply exists so that implementers of the interface don't need to implement all the methods they do not care about.

Should the class StubbedMyInterface be declared abstract? Or should it have a protected default constructor (so that e.g. a unit test for StubbedMyInterface which checks that all methods throw the desired exception can instantiate the class without creating a needless subclass)? Or should the class just be a normal public class?

UPDATE:
OK, I see I should provide more context. This problem occured while implementing a visitor pattern for an Abstract Syntax Tree. The interface defines one method per node type in the tree and these are quite a lot of types.

I have several of these Stub implementation:

1. One like the one above which is useful e.g. when processing the children of a certain node - in this case I know that only node type A,B and C can possibly be a child of the node whose children I process. And if I got this wrong I want some error message to point me to the problem.
2. One which just has empty implementations for each method - which is useful if I want to process only nodes I know what to do with and ignore the others.
3. One which by default traverses the children of each node which is useful if I want to traverse a full tree but care only about certain node types.

Comment: "The stubbed class simply exists so that implementers of the interface don't need to implement all the methods they do not care about." Sounds like your interface is defined too broad. Maybe try refactoring it into smaller, more clearly defined ones?

Comment: Your reason for this class to exist in the first place doesn't sound convincing. An implementation that doesn't actually support the interface it nominally implements is... sometimes the lesser evil, but never good. If so many implementations only support part of the interface that it's worthwhile to reduce the boilerplace of doing so, maybe something needs to be rethought?

Comment: Why bother with the interface? its not actually giving you anything if you give your code a way out of using it. Just use the abstract class... or define your interface properly...

Comment: @sheItem, delnan: In my concrete case the interface is the base for a visitor. There are some implementations of the visitor which can only work with a subset of the possible objects and if another object appears in the list it is an error.

Comment: @M21B8: Because I have several of such base implementions: One with the exceptions, one with empty methods and one that by default continues to traverse subitems (it is about a visitor in a tree structure)

Answer (score 3):

To me, this comes down to Booch. "A class should be minimalistic and complete." Is this class complete? If not, it should be abstract.

The nature of the structure isn't compelling. Is this class, on it's own, useful for something is the key factor. If not, it should be abstract.

Answer (score 1):

If some of the interface method definitions are not supposed to be implemented, then I would prefer spreading them accross several interfaces.

Then I would implement only the **exact** interface, which holds the method definitions I'm interested in.

For example:

```
interface MyFirstInterface {
    void doSomething();
}

interface MySecondInterface {
    void doSomethingElse();
}

public class MyClass implement MySecondInterface {
    void doSomethingElse() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With Java 8, you can define a default implementation in the interface itself, which gives much more flexibility than an abstract class (you can inherit multiple interfaces) - so it could look like:

```
interface MyInterface {
  default void doSomething() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
  }

  default void doSomethingElse() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
  }
  /* all the other methods */
}
```

With Java 7 and earlier, using an abstract class would make sense to provide a default basic implementation.

Comment: +1 for Java8. But what I don't understood is this: With these default implementations are you gonna be able to implement only the methods you're interested in ?

Comment: @kocko you mean whether the default will be targeted only to particular methods?

Comment: @kocko Yes - you can also define methods without implementation in the interface, and you can override (or not) default methods in subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

If implementers of the interface don't need to implement all the methods, they don't need implement this interface, they need only one interface in the hierarchy with needed method set.
I would use inheritance like this

```
interface MyFirstInterface {
    void doSomething();
}
interface MySecondInterface extends MyFirstInterface {
    void doSomethingElse();
}
```